# YouTube channels likes and dislikes

Tags: api, web-scraping, google-api, youtube, language-agnostic

Is there any feature or api provided by YouTube so that we can have a count of total number of likes & dislikes on any channel.

For ex: Considering the example of "TED" YouTube channel can we have details that how many likes,dislikes are there on the channel (i.e. summing all the videos likes& dislikes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is. On its [api reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels), at the time of this writing, in the channels section there is only the "viewCount", "commentCount", "subscriberCount", "hiddenSubscriberCount" and "videoCount" as statistics that can be obtained from a channel.